# MS Access XP/2002 Runtime Force A4 Page Size

Tags: microsoft-access

We use an ERP system that we are deploying in Europe.  The system is built by a US based company and currently all of the reporting is based on MS Access reports.  It installs with the MS Access XP/2002 Runtime version.  Is there a way (i.e. Registry Key, etc.) too force the default page size to A4 as opposed to Letter?

If not are there any other option anyone knows of?

Thanks

Comment: Page size is defined in each report layout, so you'd have to edit each one individually. It can be done in code, but it requires that the Access front end be an MDB or ACCDB -- it won't be editable with MDE/ACCDE.

Comment: Is there a way to force Windows or the Printer to simply treat Letter format as A4?  There has got to be some way to get around this without having to edit "n" number of reports.  So frustrating.

Comment: Not so far as I'm aware. I can't think of any way with an MDE/ACCDE to do this. You need an MDB or ACCDB to change the report layouts. The only possibility would be if your printer driver has the ability to save a "resize to page" setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never did find a workable way to do this.  At least not easily.  Its about the same amount of work that is required in modern reporting packages as well such as SSRS.  Either way I'm going to close this question as answered simply because no viable answers appear to exist for this particular scenario.